# Solution for running asp and php the same time on windows XP?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, php, asp

Currently I'm using wampserver to run PHP pages,

is it possible for me to integrate the support for asp with Apache?

Or I need to install another web server that's compatible with Apache to server asp pages?

Answer (score 1):

It would likely be much easier to just run both PHP and ASP on IIS. The MS [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) makes this very easy for you. Heck, it'll even install MySQL and get all the PHP bits working for you.